# ZF2 + Doctrine2 App extremly slow

Tags: doctrine-orm

I developed a ZF2 application with Doctrine 2 as ORM. The app is extremly slow, so I decided to install webgrind on my server to locate the bottleneck. There I saw, that I have an invocation count of round about 8.000 calls for the `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->createEntity` method. In another application with the same base system I come to a count of 56. At the page of the screenshot I have three database queries with a time of 13.94 ms and one of these queries has one join operation to another table.

How can I find out, where that huge amount of calls come from?

If you need further information, please let me know.

[image: Webgrind Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a callgraph that might hint at anything? If not have a look at [blackfire.io](http://blackfire.io) or [tideways.io](http://tideways.io) or xhprof if you want to/have to run it locally.